# wpf multiple binding sql and selectedItem

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid

Hi i have problem with binding. I binded data grid to result of sql query, but i dont knew how to bind selectedItem. I want to something like `SelectedItem.a`. My question is how to bind to multiple things?

This is code how i binded to `SelctedItem` but this is not working.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid  Name="grid" ItemsSource ="{Binding}" SelectedItem ="{Binding Path=SelectedItem Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <DataGrid.Columns >
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="A" Binding="{Binding Path=a, Mode=TwoWay}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="B" Binding="{Binding Path=b, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="D" Binding="{Binding Path=c, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="selectRow"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>

</DataGrid>
```

`SelectedItem` Definition:

```
 searchPizzeria _selectedItem;
 public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
       public foo SelectedItem {
            get { return _selectedItem; }
            set {
                throw new Exception();//dont rise
                this._selectedItem = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
             }
        }
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName){
            var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) {
                handler(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
```

Model:

```
public class foo {
    public string a { get; set; }
    public string b { get; set; }
    public string c { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT. I dont why it is not binding. It must be something with SelectedItem or XAML definition.

EDIT How i set data in grid

```
 adapter = new Npgsql.NpgsqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@foo", A_comboBox.Text);
            dataTable = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dataTable);
            grud.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView;
```

EDIT my first solution but i cant access hidden data

```
   DataRowView row = (DataRowView)grid.SelectedItems[0];
    var x = row["Id_user"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to bind to a single item, then your property needs to be marked as `public`:

```
public foo SelectedItem 
{ 
    ...
```

You should also check your `DataContext`, as your `ItemsSource` grid property is bound to the current `DataContext` (which is obviously a collection assuming that your items are displaying correctly in the grid), so therefore it can't also be your type that contains the `SelectedItem` property.

You want your `DataContext` to be an instance of the type that contains both the collection of items, and the `SelectedItem` property. For example a view model, if you're using the MVVM design pattern.

Comment: No i dont use MVVM. I will try that.

Comment: Sry i dont uderstand what u mean. Can u give me simple example?

Comment: Hmm. It is good advice but i need to learn MVVMM and refactor everything. I dont have any dataContext in my xaml and at the momement i am doing some random stuff from internet.
I would ask another question but i dont have any. If you would write something in your answer maybe i would now what to ask.

Comment: You say you don't have any DataContext, but you must have if there are any items in your grid, then your DataContext is your items collection. Where is this set? Do you set your DataContext declaratively in the XAML, or in the code behind instead? Either way, it's now not an appropriate data context.

Comment: I added how i set context of data grid.

Comment: If you really don't want to go with MVVM (and I mean really), then I would just hook into the selection changed event on the grid in your code behind.

Comment: Hmm but i cant get hidden value from grid. Thats is why i wanted to bind row.

Comment: I will do it in a dirty way then. I will map id grid to hidden value.